# Regex for case insensitive word Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Is there any easy way to extract values from free form text ?

I am trying to extract vales from this:

```
"The process started from ITEM: ASDE3423423, Item Group: A_GROUP, ITEM Function: ['/A/B/C'], Price Code: average."
```

I need o/p which are after ':' based on the key (e.g. ITEM, Item Group)

```
ITEM = ASDE3423423
Item Group = A_GROUP
ITEM Function = ['/A/B/C']
Price Code = average
```

I am using :

```
ITEM:\s*([^,]+)
Item Group:\s*([^,]+)
ITEM Function:\s*([^,]+)
Price Code:\s*([^,]+)
```

and splitting the string with ':' and getting str[1] for the given key (e.g. ITEM, Item Group)

Is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: Maybe [`(?:ITEM(?: GROUP| Function)?|Price Code):\s*([^\s,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/FYxCqx/1) will do.

Comment: Without hardcoding key names you can use: [`([A-Z]\w*+(?: [A-Z]\w*)*):\s*([^\s,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/YEocn5/2)

Comment: Try this one https://regex101.com/r/YEocn5/3

Comment: @anubhava It gives From ITEM for 1st ITEM

Comment: It gives both key and value in 2 groups. For first match group #1 is `ITEM` and group #2 is `ASDE3423423`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning the full match and splitting it return the capture group.

```js
// DATA STRING
var str = 'The process started from ITEM: ASDE3423423, Item Group: A_GROUP, ITEM Function: [\'/A/B/C\'], Price Code: average.',

// REGEX
reg = /ITEM:\s*([^,]+)|Item Group:\s*([^,]+)|ITEM Function:\s*([^,]+)|Price Code:\s*([^,]+)/g;

// GET MATCH
match = reg.exec(str);

// LOOP MATCH
while(match != null) {
  
  // LOG MATCH
  console.log(match[0])
  
  // TRY FOR NEXT MATCH
  match = reg.exec(str);
  
}
```